# Cassandra driver 3.4 is not compatible with Guava 30

Tags: cassandra, guava, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

We've a Java 8 standalone applicat that reads from Cassandra tables, The client version we're currently using is 3.4.0. The application should also support reading from Google Cloud Storage, but once we added the GCS dependencies to the pom file we started see exceptions when reading from Cassandra. Seems like the 3.4 driver uses Guava 19, and the GCS uses Guava 30. Is it possible to make them both live together in the same Java process? Trying to exlude Guava from the cassandra-driver-core 3.4 causing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback
    at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.selectImplementation(GuavaCompatibility.java:136)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.<clinit>(GuavaCompatibility.java:52)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:68)
    at com.myorg.infra.cassandra.CassandraConnector.basicBuilder(CassandraConnector.java:32)
    at com.myorg.infra.cassandra.CassandraConnector.connect(CassandraConnector.java:61)
    at com.myorg.aggregator.cassandra.analytics.repository.CategoryDetailsRepository.main(CategoryDetailsRepository.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureFallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Cassandra dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

GCS dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>20.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found that upgrading Cassandra driver version to [3.11.0](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/) was the best solution. It takes Guava 30 while keeping most of the driver interfaces.

Note that Cassandra driver version 4.0+ is not binary compatible, meaning you can not drop it in and hoping it works. It does require a complete re-write of application code.

As to your question,

> Is it possible to make them both live together in the same Java process?

It's possible with multiple classloaders but you may not want to do that.